# Unique Integer IDs with Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a file that generates dynamic html content using EJS and so does the IDs. The dynamic IDs that I created are in format for example "project_0". I want to know how to access the function when using these IDs without repeating the code for each ID.
App.js (NODE)

---

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res)
{
    res.render('test',{data:[{'project':'CMS'},{'project':'LMS'}, 
    {'project':'Web'}]})
})
```

test.ejs

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>

        <div id="project_<%=i%>" style="color:red;display:block"> 
    <%=data[i].project%>
        </div>

         <div id="hidden_<%=i%>" style="display:none">
     This is my last project
         </div>

         <button id="button_<%=i%>">click Me!</button>
         <br/>
         <%}%>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#button_0").click(function(){
            $("#hidden_0").show()
            $("#project_0").css("color","blue")
         })

         $("#button_1").click(function(){
            $("#hidden_1").show()
            $("#project_1").css("color","blue")
         })

         $("#button_2").click(function(){
            $("#hidden_2").show()
            $("#project_2").css("color","blue")
         })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to never use incremental `id` attributes. They are an anti-pattern.

Use common classes to group HTML structures together then use DOM traversal in JS to associate related elements, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.container');
    $container.find('.hidden').toggle()
    $container.find('.project').toggleClass('active');
  });
})
```

```css
.project {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.project.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- repeated as many times as needed in your loop... -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="project">
    data[i].project
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    This is my last project
  </div>
  <button class="button">click Me!</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="project">
    data[i].project
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    This is my last project
  </div>
  <button class="button">click Me!</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="project">
    data[i].project
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    This is my last project
  </div>
  <button class="button">click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Also note here the use of CSS classes over using `css()` to create inline styles.

Comment: But I am actually looking for how to solve that integer part of id if it is appended with id and I have to use it into my function any variable that can be used in the place of that integer would be useful.

Comment: That's my point - that's a very bad way of doing what you need. The above is more both more extensible, simpler and easier to maintain. There is absolutely no need for incremental ids.

Comment: My div is generated dynamically so for that purpose I need incremental ids, what else can be better for that then incremental ids?